# Отличия экспорта/импорта с exp и imp между CentOS и Windows

Tags: oracle, centos

Сегодня перешли с Windows Server на CentOS и установили Oracle БД.
На сервере, который был под Windows, была сделана копия БД с помощью `exp`.

Возможно ли теперь развернуть эту копию с помощью `imp` в CentOS? Команда такая же как и под Windows?

Если можно, поделитесь примером `imp` под Linux.

Comment: Никаких отличий нет, кроме разве того, что окружение должно быть установлено.

Comment: @0xdb Приблизительно пример можете привести как ответ, не доконца понял про окружение ? Спасибо большое.

Comment: Окружение надо устанавливать, потому, что реестра больше нет.
А impdp действительно без изменений - `impdp scott/tiger@db10g schemas=SCOTT directory=TEST_DIR dumpfile=SCOTT.dmp logfile=impdpSCOTT.log`.

Comment: @0xdb Спасибо за ответ и разъяснение.

Comment: Рад был помочь! Если что-то ещё непонятно - обращяйтесь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В отличае от Windows, окружение необходимо устанавливать, потому что реестра нет:

```
$ export ORACLE_SID=orcl; .oraenv
```

Рекомендуется включить эту строку в ~/.profile.

---

Команды импорта на разных платформах ничем не отличаются. Исключение - специальные символы, которые могут интерпретироватся по разному в коммандной строке. Если таковые имеются, то параметры проще читать из файла заданного параметром `PARFILE`:

```
$ imp PARFILE=params.txt
```

или:

```
$ impdp PARFILE=params.txt
```